# React Native - change others components style onPress

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

For example, when onPress 2, other 1,3,4 style will become `noselected`, and 2 become `selected`.

```
<TopNav>
  <NavItem onPress={()=> this.ChooseThis()} style={styles.selected}>1</NavItem>
  <NavItem onPress={()=> this.ChooseThis()} style={styles.noselected}>2</NavItem>
  <NavItem onPress={()=> this.ChooseThis()} style={styles.noselected}>3</NavItem>
  <NavItem onPress={()=> this.ChooseThis()} style={styles.noselected}>4</NavItem>
</TopNav>
```

Comment: Please make your question more clear. I assume you are asking help on how to implement that behaviour and not how to solve a problem. Did you try something before asking here?

Comment: @arracso i do this kind of research for hole day, cannot find any similar result

Comment: A fast option is to use state to save the item that is current-ly being selected. So instead of passong nothing to ChooseThis(). Pass him the name of the Item or a Integer. And on style compare the state with that name.

Comment: If you can get to the answer I will post one fully explained later

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achive that. One of these is to use the state of the parent component. I don't know whats your code structure, but lets assume its like this:

```
class Nav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  ChooseThis = () => { /* Some code*/ };

  render(){
    return (<TopNav>
      <NavItem onPress={()=> this.ChooseThis()} style={styles.selected}>1</NavItem>
      <NavItem onPress={()=> this.ChooseThis()} style={styles.noselected}>2</NavItem>
      <NavItem onPress={()=> this.ChooseThis()} style={styles.noselected}>3</NavItem>
      <NavItem onPress={()=> this.ChooseThis()} style={styles.noselected}>4</NavItem>
    </TopNav>);
  }
}
```

If you are using a stateless component (not creating a class), you may want to rewrite your code like I done.

Ok now lets add a state that will controls what Item is selected. In my case I will call it "selected" and his value will be 1 (can be a string or something else if you want).

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selected: 1 };
  }
```

Now I will use the function `ChooseThis()` to alse change the state. To do that I will pass him the selected item name/index/ref.

```
  ChooseThis = (index) => {
    this.setState({ selected: index });
    /* Some other code*/
  };
```

Finally on every Item I will set its index/name/ref and on their styles check if it is the current selected item.

```
  render(){
    const selected = this.state.selected;
    return (<TopNav>
      <NavItem onPress={()=> this.ChooseThis(1)} style={selected == 1 ? styles.selected : styles.noselected}>1</NavItem>
      <NavItem onPress={()=> this.ChooseThis(2)} style={selected == 2 ? styles.selected : styles.noselected}>2</NavItem>
      <NavItem onPress={()=> this.ChooseThis(3)} style={selected == 3 ? styles.selected : styles.noselected}>3</NavItem>
      <NavItem onPress={()=> this.ChooseThis(4)} style={selected == 4 ? styles.selected : styles.noselected}>4</NavItem>
    </TopNav>);
  }
}
```

And thats all you need.

Comment: i change `{selected == 4 ? styles.selected : styles.noselected}` to `{this.state.selected == 4 ? styles.selected : styles.noselected}` the error is gone, but nothing happen, click 2, the 2 still no selected